# Prevent Firefox from making a new contenteditable div when user hits return

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div on my site which works great.

On Chrome i can just use the return key to add another line.

On Firefox it creates a new (extra) div.

I know I can use shift+return, but I don't think the users will now that :)

Is it possible to prevent this behaviour?

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D7MJx/

I've tried it with FF 3.6

EDIT: The same thing happens on IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I kinda figured it out now.

It's not the best (read cleanest) solution, but it works for me.

Only have tested this on Chrome, but I think other browsers will work the same.

I ended up doing this:

```
  $('div[contenteditable=true]').keydown(function(e) {
    // trap the return key being pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      // insert 2 br tags (if only one br tag is inserted the cursor won't go to the second line)
      document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
      // prevent the default behaviour of return key pressed
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: It's not that simple. You have to consider a couple of special cases, for example in `<ul>`s. Look at https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/jscripts/tiny_mce/classes/ForceBlocks.js to see how tinymce does it.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: I will look into it. Although I have a real simple contenteditable. Just some basic bold tagging etc. So no `ul`'s and other (fancy :P ) stuff

Comment: You can alway paste arbitrary markup into a contentediable region, unless you filter the paste process (which is a difficult task too)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `insertBrOnReturn` command.

```
document.getElementById('myRichEditArea').contentDocument.execCommand('insertBrOnReturn',false, true)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla

The Mozilla docs say `insertBrOnReturn` is not supported by IE but the docs are old and probably means IE7 or below. There's probably another way to do it in IE.

Comment: When I use that code I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'execCommand' of undefined` (in Chrome)

Comment: When I use that code I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'execCommand' of undefined (2)

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira In 2011 this was very experimental stuff. A lot can change in 7 years. Try the updated docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content